# View flipper did not remove not displayed child if animation is added

Tags: android, animation, view, viewflipper, transition

**edited:**
To summarize If I have animation on view transition The problem appears, but as soon as I remove the animation form the view, the not displayed child at view flipper dis apear as, well.

I have created a view flipper it works nicely I have set some animation too, but one bug appeared for example.[image: first scree][image: second screen][image: bug at third screen]. Like on screens below can be seen I have one list view if I click on random row the view is translated. the code : `((ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.in_app_vf)).setDisplayedChild(1);` after that I click back button the first view appears code : `((ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.in_app_vf)).setDisplayedChild(0);` but the problem is that when I click on the same space where the editText was it calls the keyboard. So the list view is not clickable at positions where the editText field was. I can not find Where the problem is.

the out animation I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="-100%p"
        android:duration="700"/>

    <alpha 
        android:fromAlpha="1.0" 
        android:toAlpha="0.0" 
        android:duration="900" />
</set>
```

The code which I tried to remove unused views, but it is not working:

```
private void setAllTheOtherViewGone(){
        for(int i = 0; i <= ((ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.in_app_vf)).getChildCount()-1;i++)
            if(i != ((ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.in_app_vf)).getDisplayedChild()){
                ((ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.in_app_vf)).getChildAt(i).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ((ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.in_app_vf)).getChildAt(i).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
    }
```

Comment: If I disable animation it works like it should

Answer (score 0):

Set the property of edittext setFocusable(false) and setFocusableInTouchmode(false) may it work.

Comment: But it appear every where, for example if i click at 2. view everywhere where outside of the editext it appears like i have clicked on list view and calls the 2.view once more